# Firing an event: from source to listener to action

Tags: java, events, awt, listener, actionlistener

I'm trying to implement an event/listener system that's similar to Java, however I'm a bit confused in this part.

For example let's look at the `ActionEvent` class. We have an `ActionEvent` that is fired by an object that gets passed on into the object's `ActionListener`.

First, how does the source know when to fire an event? My guess is that if a certain condition is met (such as being pressed), it makes an `ActionEvent` with the appropriate parameters, then "fires" it.

And next, what methods are involved with this and event handling? I was looking at `Component` and it had `processComponentEvent` where an event gets passed in into the listener. However what about `ActionEvents` where the source is an `Object`? Where is the `processEvent` method that can handle this type of event?

Comment: have you looked into eventbus, like guava's? http://codingjunkie.net/guava-eventbus/

Comment: Look up the Observer design pattern. As for firing events, that's determined by the meaning of whatever the event is. If it's a `PropertyChangeEvent`, for example, the source needs to fire it whenever a property changes.

Comment: Take a look at [Writing JavaBeans Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/). That might help you out.

Comment: I'll take a look at eventbus but I'm coding this in another language. I actually looked at the Observer design pattern before starting but it's too simple.. does Java employ a similar system? I'm mostly curious on where this `processEvent` method is.

Comment: You should be able to write good interfaces and mandate your classes in your system to implement them where necessary. You need to design an excellent architecture to do your own event generate/ listen mechanism I believe. this is theoretical question and I fear someone would downvote our posts.

Comment: @sivatumma I'm mostly interested in the code to see how exactly an event flow through Java. And yes I already have an architecture ready complete with interfaces and Abstract classes (though of course not closet to Java's). I'm not really asking how to generate a similar system, but how does the system work in a technical level.